# Stange seg fault when using += with strings

Tags: c++, std

There must be something obvious I don't realize about C++ with this one.

```
load(string & filename){

 string command;
 char delimiter = '/';
 size_t delimiterPos = filename.rfind(delimiter);
 string directory = string(filename.c_str(),delimiterPos);
 command = "import path ";

  //want to add directory to end of command
  string temp = command + "hello!"; // This works
  command.append(directory); //This works!
  command += directory;  //This seg faults!
  ...
}
```

in GDB when I "print" filename at the beginning of the function I get:
(const string &) @0x9505f08: {static npos = 4294967295,
  _M_dataplus = {> = {<__gnu_cxx::new_allocator> = {}, }, _M_p = 0x950a8e4 "../config/pythonFile.py"}}

What the heck, how is filename formatted incorrectly, such that .append() works and += doesn't?! Something strange in the overloaded function += in C++?

g++ version 3.4.6

Comment: Break into the operator+= function to see what actual line it's crashing on.

Comment: What happens if you reverse the order of calls to append and += ? Or were you trying them one at a time?

Comment: @harper dies on the += and never gets to the .append

Comment: I tried out your code, and it works like a charm. Which compiler are you using?

Comment: Also, try: string temp = "hello"; command += temp; does that work?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it has to do with how you are constructing "directory" here

```
 size_t delimiterPos = filename.rfind(delimiter);
 string directory = string(filename.c_str(),delimiterPos);
```

Is rfind somehow failing? If rfind failed, it would return std::npos as specified [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d994he8y(VS.80).aspx). I'm not sure what the behavior would be if you passed npos into the string constructor. It may be platform dependent.

This doesn't answer why "append" would work and "+=" would crash. You may also have some kind of heap corruption (maybe caused by the npos and C string passed into the constructor above) and maybe when += is called new memory needs to be allocated. Append for whatever reason may not need to allocate new memory.

In any case, it would be wise to add a check for npos.

Comment: I suspect you may be right, I am trying to track down memory corruption using valgrind.

Comment: You win the cookie.  One of the strings wasn't being allocated correctly in the library.  The fact that += allocates off the heap, apparently, causing the problem.

Answer (score 1):

I can not reproduce your problem. The file below works here with g++:

```
#include <string>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main(int, char**)
{
 string filename("a/b/c/d");

 string command;
 char delimiter = '/';
 size_t delimiterPos = filename.rfind(delimiter);
 string directory = string(filename.c_str(),delimiterPos);
 command = "import path ";

  //want to add directory to end of command
  string temp = command + "hello!"; // This works
  command.append(directory); //This works!
  cout << command << endl;

  command += directory;  //This seg faults!
  cout << command << endl;

}
```

Output:

```
$ g++ -o t t.cpp
$ ./t
import path a/b/c
import path a/b/ca/b/c
```